# How To Eager load a Method in model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `product` model that has a method that returns the `price` of a `product`

```
public function ProductSeller()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSeller','product_id')->get();
}

public function price()
{
    $productSellers = $this->ProductSeller();
    foreach ($productSellers as $productSeller){
        $productPrice[]=$productSeller->price;
    }

    if (empty($productPrice) == true || min($productPrice) == '0'){
        $Rprice = 'call for price';
    } else {
        $Rprice = number_format(min($productPrice));
    }

    return $Rprice;
}
```

The problem is I want to Eager load it and get the `price` like `$product->price` but I get `App\Product::price must return a relationship instance`.

Anybody can help me with it?

Comment: `price` isn't a relationship method so there is no 'eager loading' for that ... you have model accessors for something like this

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done via **accessor** and gladly, you have already gone through half of the steps. Just change the name of your method in model as per Laravel's accessor naming convention like this:

```
public function ProductSeller()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSeller','product_id');
}



public function GetPriceAttribute()
{
    $productSellers = $this->ProductSeller;
    foreach ($productSellers as $productSeller){
        $productPrice[]=$productSeller->price;
    }

    if (empty($productPrice) == true || min($productPrice) == '0'){
        $Rprice = 'call for price';
    } else {
    $Rprice = number_format(min($productPrice));
    }

    return $Rprice;
}
```

Now, you can easily access the method like:

```
$product->price;
```

**Note: In the model, get() function is removed from the end of the relationship and also, the relationship method is called without adding parenthesis in the GetPriceAttribute() method. This approach worked for me.**

Comment: @Vahidmarali, I am glad it was helpful. You can mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks, I did it it was helpful but i still got a problem it still makes one duplicated query once in the model and once in my blade can you help me with it too?

Comment: please add duplicated query and the result in your question

Comment: ***select * from `product_sellers` where `product_sellers`.`product_id` =111111 and `product_sellers`.product_id` is not null***

I have this query get duplicate in my debugbar once in App\Product.PHP and once on the category page while I just used $product->price